# Values of $m$ for which $y^2 + 2xy + 2x -my -3$ can be factorised

Tags: rational-functions

> For what values of $m$, will the expression $y^2 + 2xy + 2x -my -3$ be capable of resolution into two rational linear factor?

This is how I did it:
$$y^2 + 2xy + 2x -my -3 = y^2+(2x-m)y+2x-3$$
This can always be factorized if $b^2-4ac>0$, so if $4ac$ will be negative ($\forall x\in(-\infty,3/2)$), then $b^2-4ac > 0,   . $ We need to only worry about $x>\frac32$.
I tried using the quadratic formula next, but couldn't get any further .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** The factorization can be taken to have shape $(y+ax+b)(y+cx+d)$. Since there is no $x^2$ term, we have $a=0$ or $c=0$. We can take $c=0$. The term in $xy$ is $2xy$, so $a=2$. Continue. We are pretty close to the end.

**Added:** Your discriminant approach will also work. The discriminant is 
$(2x-m)^2-4(2x-3)$. This expands to $4x^2-4x(m+2)+m^2+12$.

This discriminant must be the square of something linear in $x$. So the discriminant of the polynomial $4x^2-4x(m+2)+m^2+12$ must be $0$. We get
$16(m+2)^2-16(m^2+12)=0$. Solve for $m$.

Comment: That was the hint that my Math Teacher gave me...But I thought that maybe there'd be some other way around.

Comment: Might as well use basic detective work, nothing fancy. The discriminant approach will also work.

Comment: It would be great if  you could perhaps help me with the discrimant approach.

Comment: Why must the discriminant be the square of something linear in x?

Comment: So that when we "solve" for $y$ in terms of $x$ (Quadratic Formula), the expression(s) for $y$ will be linear in $x$.

Comment: But why does the discriminant have to be the square of something linear in x for that?

Comment: The first hint gave me the answer, but I want to know about the added one.

Comment: Imagine we have factored our expression, as in the hint. (But now we go along the discriminant path.) Then the solutions of $P(y)=0$ are linear in $x$ (they are $-ax-b$ and $-cx-d$). So the expression given by the Quadratic Formula must be linear in $x$, meaning that the discriminant is the square of a linear polynomial.

Comment: So I must first know the equation in first hint.

Comment: You must know the *meaning* of "can be factorized."

Comment: That makes me realize that I never read the linear factor part...All I read was "factor"...Darn it! Thank you so much!

Comment: You are welcome. Congratulations on pushing until everything was clear.

Comment: @shaurya You can factor it more simply without solving systems of equations or discriminants, because if the constant term of  a quadratic polynomial is prime (or has few factorizations) then this greatly constraints the possible factorizations of the polynomial - see my answer. What hint did your teacher supply?

Answer (score 2):

Try pulling out a factor of $y$ from every term with a common $y$ factor, and you'll see that your expression can be written as $y(y+2x-m)+2x-3$.  Now, the non-$y$ terms look similar to each other; the term $2x$ shows up twice, and there's a constant along with it in each spot. This suggests trying $m=3$, which gives $y(y+2x-3)+(2x-3)$.  This is *close*, but it's not quite factorable; OTOH, can you see how to add a term to this expression that would let you pull out another simple factor?  Once you do that, multiply the two terms back and you should have your answer...

Comment: What does "multiply the two terms back" refer to?

Comment: I added and subtracted $y$, which gave $y(y+2x-m-1)+(y+2x-3)$, which can always be factorized if $m=2$.

Comment: Totally Awesome!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ p = 2x\!-\!3$ is prime, so $\,y^2\! + \color{#c00}b\, y + p = (y\pm p)(y\pm 1) = y^2\color{#c00}{\pm (p\!+\!1)}\,y + p.\ $ Therefore $\, \color{#c00}{b = \pm(p\!+\!1)},\,$ i.e. $\, 2x\!-\!m = \pm (2x\!-\!2)\,\Rightarrow\, m = 2\ \ $ **QED**

Comment: But what if $2x-3$ is not prime?

Comment: @shaurya It is prime (irreducible) as a *polynomial* in $\,x.\ \ $